# Flutter making FadeIn ZoomIn dialog like with Instagram overlay

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

This below code can make a simple dialog which that can transform from bottom and my question is how can i change that to transform from center of screen such as ZoomIn with the FadeIn effect?

```dart
showGeneralDialog(
  barrierLabel: 'label',
  barrierDismissible: true,
  barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  context: context,
  pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) {
    return const NotificationSheet();
  },
  transitionBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: CurvedAnimation(parent: anim1, curve: Curves.easeOut),
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: Tween(begin: const Offset(0, 0.1), end: const Offset(0, 0)).animate(anim1),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use ScaleTransition in place of FadeTransition and FadeTransition in place of SlideTransition.

- ScaleTransition for ZoomIn
- FadeTransition for FadeIn

Here is your refactored code:

```
showGeneralDialog(
              barrierLabel: 'label',
              barrierDismissible: true,
              barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
              context: context,
              pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) {
                return const NotificationSheet();                  },
              transitionBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) {
                return ScaleTransition(
                  scale:
                      CurvedAnimation(parent: anim1, curve: Curves.easeOut),
                  child: FadeTransition(
                    opacity: CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: anim1, curve: Curves.easeOut),
                    child: child,
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: this code transform dialog from center to bottom, how can i change that to zoom-in it to center of screen not bottom?

Comment: this code perfectly does what you want. I have tested it again. Dialog appears from center and then fades out in the center when closed.

Comment: Dialog appears from center and goes to bottom of screen after when animation finished. i tested that on android

Comment: Okay, so you have to make sure your content is centered in pageBuilder. Try parent widget as Column. You can see the example here [Output](https://imgur.com/N0WmFUG)